# WiMax/4G on Android API (2.3.3)

Tags: android, sdk, android-sdk-2.3, 4g, wimax

I need to create a program that would turn on 4G/WiMax (On an Evo 4G) off or on (based on current state).

I was digging around the API and noticed there is not a lot of mentioning of WiMax or 4G.  I noticed: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html - but still I can't get WiMax to toggle on or off using the following code bit.

```
// get phone state
ConnectivityManager cm =
    (ConnectivityManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

cm.startUsingNetworkFeature(cm.TYPE_WIMAX, "4g");
```

Thank you.  I know this is possible i am just not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the next person to run into this problem heres the solution when it comes to MOST HTC phones that are wimax capable:

```
//make the object
Object wimaxManager = (Object)getBaseContext().getSystemService("wimax");

//declare the method
Method setWimaxEnabled = wimaxManager.getClass().getMethod("setWimaxEnabled", new Class[] { Boolean.TYPE });

//turn it on
setWimaxEnabled.invoke(wimaxManager, new Object[] { Boolean.TRUE });

//turn it off
setWimaxEnabled.invoke(wimaxManager, new Object[] { Boolean.FALSE });
```

There we go :)